Problem with importing pandas package due to pandas co-dependency being unavailable
I am having an issue with being unable to import pandas due to a certain pandas package being missing for some reason. When I run the cell in my jupyter notebook I get the following error.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.parsers'

I am using python 3.13, and I have the main pandas package install through miniconda. I also have the latest version of scikit-learn, matplotlib, seaborn, and numpy installed. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling the pandas package as well as all my other packages, and nothing seems to work.

I wouldn't suggest uninstalling and reinstalling miniconda, unless this is the first and only environment you set up, but see here for a troubleshooting suggestion. Or at least maybe to get past this hurdle if all else seems fine. If you want more specific suggestions, it would be helpful to have more details. You write, "I tried uninstalling then reinstalling the pandas package as well as all my other packages, and nothing seems to work." Where and how did you do those things?

I have a miniconda local environment running with the stated version of python. When I said I uninstalled the reinstalled all of my packages I meant in my local environment.

What is your pandas version? the error traceback message could be useful (or an extract if too long).

pandas version 2.2.3, and yes the traceback message is long

What code did you run that got that error? import pandas? Please [edit] the question to include this and other details you've mentioned in the comments, in order to keep all the info together. And please add the full error message with traceback. If import pandas does actually work, then do that and show us the output of print(pandas). This is primarily to check if you accidentally overrode the module.

Installing python 3.12.8 solved the issue. Before I was using 3.13
